# tuple inside another tuple in OCAML

Tags: tuples, ocaml

My question is in the title, here is an example :

```
(int * string * string * int * (string * string * int) list)
```

Can i do something like that ? I tryed but it didn't work, i was wondering if there was a way to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply :

```
type t = int * string * string * int * (string * string * int) list;;
```

Answer (score 2):

Pierre G. explained how to define the type.  If you wanted to know how to create such a tuple, you can do it without first defining the type.  Just construct a tuple with the data you want.  For example:

```
(1, "two", "three", 4, [("five", "six", 7); ("eight", "nine", 10)]);;
```

returns

```
int * string * string * int * (string * string * int) list =
(1, "two", "three", 4, [("five", "six", 7); ("eight", "nine", 10)])
```